# MATLAB continue function skips the wrong interation

Tags: matlab, for-loop, continue

I have a "triple nested" for loop. I have a continue in my last for loop when it is equal to the first for loop (see code) I've tried to debug the issue in a separate function to see if I was missing something, but the for loop works fine in principle by itself. The issue is that when run, the continue function jumps out of the current for loop and into the second for loop. I've never seen a continue function do this, and I've tried about everything I can think of to make it right.

Here's the code:

```
for i = 1:n
    acc = 0; 
    for c = 0:2 
        disp(i); **<---for loop continues to here instead of in the "j" for loop and going to j = 2**
        disp(c);
        for j = 1:n
            disp(j);
            if i == j
                continue;
            else
                if c == 0
                    acc = acc + (m(j)/r(i,j))*(r0(3*j)-r0(3*i));
                else
                    acc = acc + (m(j)/r(i,j))*(r0((3*(j-1))+c)-r0((3*(i-1))+c));
                end
            end
            %multiplying by gravitational constant
            acc = G*acc;
            %defining velocity in terms of acceleration
            if c == 0
                dy(3*n+(3*i)) = acc;
            else
                dy(3*n+(3*(i-1)+c)) = acc;
            end
            disp(dy)
        end
    end
end
```

Here's the output:

```
n_body
@setup

 1

 0

 1

 1

 1

 1
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: what is the value of`n`?

Comment: It's set at the beginning of the function. For my work, it's either 2, 3, or 4. I'm getting the issues on n = 2 (so far, could be the others too)

Comment: Show output during the error case

Comment: Paratheses mine:

n_body
    @setup

1   (x)

0   (c)

1   (j)

     1   (x)

     1   (c)

     1   (j)

Comment: Make it an edit to your question. Also, can you add a printout for `n` before the loop just to be sure.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the issue. I just figured my length of the matrix was working properly. My matrix m is m = [5,5]. I did n = length(m), and it returns "1" for n. Is length the wrong thing to use here?

Comment: Yes. Use either `numel(m)` or `length(m')`. Length is always the number of rows.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MadPhysicist `length` isn't "always" the number of rows in `m`.  It is the largest non-singleton dimension in your vector/matrix. For example, given a 4 x 6 x 8 x 3 x 2 matrix, `length` would report 8.  Using `length` gives a false sense of security when being used with vectors as there is only one non-singleton dimension. As such, applying this to matrices and multi-dimensional data is a common source of bugs.  If I can coin a phrase from user [@chappjc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2778484/chappjc), **never** use `length`.  **Ever**.

Comment: @rayryeng. Agreed. `numel` is always safer since it does not generally presuppose anything that may not be true. It is generally safe to use `length(x(:))`, but not always possible (e.g. if `x` is an expression). I should have said `length(m(:))` instead of `length(m')` in my previous comment.